# On finding a strict Liapunov function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions, basins-of-attraction

I need to find a strict Liapunov function for this system at the equilibrium point $(0,0)$
$$x'= -2x-y^{2}$$
$$y'=-y-x^{2}$$
Also need to determine $\delta > 0$ as large as possible so that the open disk of radius $\delta$ and center $(0,0)$ is contained in the basin of attraction  of $(0,0)$.

(by definition, the basin of  attraction is the set of all initial conditions whose solutions tend to the equilibrium.)

I've tried the famed function $$L(x,y)=x^{2} + y^{2}$$ as a Liapunov function, but the problem is that all I get as the basin of attraction is only the first quadrant, for which of course there's no open disk of radius $\delta$ at the center $(0,0)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The basin of attraction of $L$ contains the unit ball $x^2+y^2\lt1$, not only its first quadrant.

Comment: $\dot L$ is strictly negative only in the first quadrant.

Comment: No. (Bis repetita.)

Comment: Beg your pardon ?

Comment: May I suggest that you provide a specific point $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$ such that $x^2+y^2\lt1$ and $L'(x,y)\geqslant0$?

Comment: Alright. How do you prove $\dot L$ is negative inside the unit circle ? My attempts seem to get to nowhere....

Comment: I finally managed to prove it using elementary nonlinear programming techniques. You were right.

Comment: "nonlinear programming techniques" Mwahaha... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can try the Lyapunov Function candidate  $V =\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{Px}$, for any positive-definite, symmetric $\mathbf P$.

The derivative along the lines of the system are of the form

$\dot V = -[\mathbf{x^T Q x + 2x^TPg}(x,y)]$,

where$\mathbf g(x,y) := (x^2 \quad y^2)^T$. Moreover, $\mathbf Q= \mathbf Q ^T >0$ satisfies the Algebraic Lyapunov Equation

$-\mathbf Q = \mathbf{PA + A^TP}$.

And

$\mathbf A := \begin{pmatrix} -2&\phantom{-}0\\\phantom{-}0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Now, you can assume that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq\delta$ so as to find a bound on the term $\mathbf {x^TPg}(x,y)$ and ensure that $V>0$ and  $\dot V<0~\forall \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq\delta$.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!